# Jquery hover function for single div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

in my gallery, Div's generating through a loop. There I want to give a hover effect for a particular (single) Div. In my code when I hover the particular div effects show to whole divs.

my code

```
.spanstyle{opacity:1;}  

while (loop){
<div class="waz">
<span class="spanstyle"></span>

</div>
}

$(".waz .spanstyle").each(function(i, val) {
    $(this).mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300);
    })
    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: .3 }, 100);
    })
});
```

for more detail, you can check the project :
[Project](http://designsolv.com/projects/mindyolk1/gallery/mind-yolk-case-studies.html)

Comment: You have this events attached to the spanstyle, not to the waz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one and check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pn55Z/) might help you

```
$(".waz").each(function(i, val) {
    $(this).mouseenter(function() {
       $('.spanstyle',this).show();
    })
   $(this).mouseleave(function() {
       $('.spanstyle',this).hide();
   })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are giving the same Id to all the divs. Try giving them different Id's

```
var i=0;
while (loop){
<div id="'waz' + i"></div>
i++;
}
```

your `$("#waz .spanstyle").each( ...`

will become

```
$("div[id='^waz'] .spanstyle").each(...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple elements with same Id. I would suggest something like this:

```
while (loop){
    <div onmouseover="a" onmouseout="b"></div>
}

function a(){
     $(this).find('.spanstyle').stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300);  
}

function b(){
     $(this).find('.spanstyle').stop().animate({ opacity: .3 }, 100);
}
```

EDIT:

Or you can do some little changes in your code:

```
$(".waz").each(function(i, val) {
    $(this).mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).children('.spanstyle').stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300);
    })
    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).children('.spanstyle').stop().animate({ opacity: .3 }, 100);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there are some conflicts in your html page. **WAZ** is an class name for some divs and for some its an ID(id should be unique in a document). I think the hover effect is coming from the below code(available in your page) :

```
$(".waz").hover(function(){ 
    $(".spanstyle").slideToggle();  
});
```

not from the code you posted in the question section. Please have a look at those things.